# Extending REST API, route to custom method

Tags: api, rest-api

I have a custom module that implements a few new REST endpoints, which is working correctly.

In my `api2.xml` I have the routes defined as this:

```
<routes>
   <route_catalog_rule>
      <route>/unir/catalogrule/:id_rule</route>
      <action_type>entity</action_type>
   </route_catalog_rule>

   <route_catalog_rules_by_any_field_id>
      <route>/unir/catalogrules/:id_name/:id_value</route>
      <action_type>collection</action_type>
   </route_catalog_rules_by_any_field_id>

   <route_catalog_rule_add>
      <route>/unir/catalogrules/add</route>
      <action_type>collection</action_type>
   </route_catalog_rule_add>
</routes>
```

And I have the appropriate `_retrieve()`, `_retrieveCollection()`, and `_create()` in the corresponding `V1.php`. All works as intended so far.

But... I need to add a new endpoint for this resource, hopefully handled by the same controller. It would also be a PUT/update (normally handled by `_update()`), but that I'd like to handle with a different method within my controller.

Basically, it comes down to either being able to specify a custom handler directly, something looking like:

```
<route_catalog_rule_disable>
  <route>/unir/catalogrules/disable/:id</route>
  <action_type>entity</action_type>
  <action_name>my_custom_handler</action_name>
</route_catalog_rule_disable>
```

Or at least to be able to pass an additional param through the route definition directly, something like:

```
<route_catalog_rule_disable>
  <route>/unir/catalogrules/disable/:id</route>
  <action_type>entity</action_type>
  <my_custom_param>disable</my_custom_param>
```

I guess that I could check do something like always going through `_update` checking pathinfo and decide according to that... but it doesn't seem too clean.